# NullFirst y DescNullLast en TFDTable de Firedac

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Me encuentro trabajando en Delphi XE7 con su característica FireDAC actualmente con el SGBD SQL Server, pero también con Oracle, he notado que con SQL Server en las propiedades de NullFirst y DescNullLast del TFDTable el valor que tienen es TRUE pero para Oracle se encuentran sin ningún valor, he realizado una investigación y he encontrado que en SQL Server no se cuenta con las propiedades NullFirst y DescNullLast en la clausula Order By y en Oracle si, ¿saben por qué entonces para SQL Server el valor predeterminado para estas propiedades es TRUE y para el caso de Oracle no tiene ningún valor?
Espero puedan ayudarme de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien el ANSI SQL no especifica nada al respecto, la extensión `SQL:2003` si menciona la posibilidad de modificar el orden de los `NULL` mediante el modificador `NULLS FIRST/LAST` de la clausula [`ORDER BY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by).

Sin embargo, los motores no adhieren totalmente a este estándar, en el caso de **Oracle** (y **PostgreSQL**) si respetan esto y entonces es posible configurar esta capacidad para que en cualquier consulta los `NULL` aparezcan al principio o al final con independencia del `ORDER BY ASC/DESC`.

**SQL Server**, por el contrario no implementa esto, y siempre los valores `NULL` aparecen al comienzo (`ORDER BY ASC`) o al final (`ORDER BY DESC`). De esto seguramente es que la propiedad (NullFirst) que mencionas, en el caso de este motor, sea `TRUE`.

Comment: Pero en SQL Server lo que pasa es que al ordenar de manera ASC los valores null si se muestran al principio, pero al ordenar por DESC se muestran al final, y esto es caso contrario con Oracle, entonces por eso es mi duda que esten en TRUE

Comment: Claro, en cualquier motor va a pasar esto, los `NULL` siguen el `ORDER BY`, la diferencia es que Oracle, además podés configurar dónde querés que se vean los `NULL` con independencia del `ORDER`, al principio `NULLS FIRST`  o al final `NULLS LAST`. Esto en SQL Server no existe, orden de los `NULL` siempre sigue al `ASC/DESC`

Comment: Pero eso lo puedes solucionar anteponiendo al order by un case when tuColumna is null then 1 else 0 end, tuColumna, y con eso, ya pasas los null al final.

Comment: Si @Javifer2, efectivamente, no lo aclaré, por que la pregunta pasa por otro lado.

Comment: He realizado pruebas ya con el componente de TFDTable de FireDAC con ambos gestores y los resultados que obtuve fueron diferentes, identifique que para que los resultados sean iguales cuando en SQL Server sea ASC en Oracle debe de ser NULLS FIRST y cuando en SQL Server sea DESC en Oracle debe de ser DESC NULLS LAST, saben en que parte del TFDTable se debe de configurar para obtener que se agregue NULLS FIRST y DESC NULLS LAST cuando se utilice Oracle